# Python Parse file with Regex

Tags: python, regex, parsing, nmap

I am hoping someone might be able to get me on the right track here.  I need to parse nmap output with Python.  I think using regex is going to be the right method for this, but I have never worked with regex.  Here is a sample of the text I need to parse --> http://pastebin.com/QhG86D7D

What I need to do with this file is:

1. I need the IP addresses.
2. I need the open ports.

The trick is I need to obviously keep the IP and ports tied together as I will be importing them into a database that will show what ports are open for each IP.

I am also thinking I should write the logic into a function so I can parse different files with larger numbers of hosts.

I do know how to read the file into my script and put the data into my database.  Where I am stuck is with the regex to parse out the data I need.  Can someone help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach should get you started:

```
import re

nmap = """Host: 127.0.0.1 ()      Status: Up
Host: 127.0.0.1 ()      Ports: 22/open/tcp//ssh///, 80/open/tcp//http///, 443/open/tcp//https///        Ignored State: closed (65532)
Host: 127.0.0.2 ()      Status: Up
Host: 127.0.0.2 ()      Ports: 21/open/tcp//ftp///, 22/open/tcp//ssh///, 25/open/tcp//smtp///, 53/filtered/tcp//domain///, 80/open/tcp//http///, 110/open/tcp//pop3///, 143/open/tcp//imap///, 443/open/tcp//https///, 465/filtered/tcp//smtps///, 993/open/tcp//imaps///, 995/open/tcp//pop3s///, 5222/filtered/tcp//xmpp-client///    Ignored State: closed (65523)
# Nmap done at Sat Nov  7 10:40:36 2015 -- 2 IP addresses (2 hosts up) scanned in 32.07 seconds"""

entries = []

for line in nmap.split('\n'):
    re_host = re.match(r'Host\: ([0-9.]+?)\s+', line)
    if re_host:
        host = re_host.group(1)
        ports = re.findall('(\d+)\/open', line)

        if len(ports):
            entries.append((host,  ports))

for host, ports in entries:
    print '{:16} {}'.format(host, ports)
```

This would display the following output:

```
127.0.0.1        ['22', '80', '443']
127.0.0.2        ['21', '22', '25', '80', '110', '143', '443', '993', '995']
```

You would want to replace the `split` with reading from your file.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

There's already a Python module for parsing Nmap scan output. For Python 3, there's [python-nmap](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-nmap). For Python 2, Nmap ships with a tool called [Ndiff](https://nmap.org/ndiff/), which is a fully-featured Nmap output parser library with a small driver to produce diffs.

These modules all parse Nmap's XML output (produced with the `-oX` option). This is the best option, since normal (human-readable) output is subject to change from version to version and Grepable output (your example) is deprecated, meaning that it hasn't provided output from any new Nmap version for a long time: traceroute, NSE, port state reasons, [CPE](http://cpe.mitre.org/) for software and OS versions, etc. are not represented.